# How to run Amazon Linux 2 on Apple Silicon

Tags: arm, amazon-linux, apple, arm64, parallels

Amazon Linux 2 -- historically a cloud offering -- is also offered as an [on-premise](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/amazon-linux-2-virtual-machine.html) solution for various setups.

The two most popular on-premise solutions are:

- Virtual Machine (e.g. KVM, Oracle VirtualBox, VMware, Microsoft Hyper-V)
- Container (i.e. Docker)

However, for convenience and simplicity, I would like to run Amazon Linux 2 in Parallels on Apple Silicon (e.g. M1 CPU).

What I've tried:

- Install [Homewbrew](https://brew.sh/)
- Install `qemu` to get access to the `qemu-convert`

  ```bash
  brew install qemu
  ```
- Download the [`kvm` "qcow2" ARM64 image](https://cdn.amazonlinux.com/os-images/2.0.20220419.0/kvm-arm64/) of Amazon Linux 2
- Convert the image to "vdi" format:

  ```bash
  qemu-img convert -f qcow2 amzn2-kvm-2.qcow2 -O vdi amzn2-kvm-2.vdi
  ```

... however Parallels says the following:

> "Parallels doesn't support the EFI boot loader for this guest OS type or architecture"

[image]

I've also tried to edit the VM's `config.pvs` with an XML editor and via [bios flag](https://kb.parallels.com/en/122735) to try to disable EFI without success, Parallels will always say something like "A critical error has occurred while reading/writing to Hard Disk 0 used by Amazon Linux 2".

Crosspost to the same question on Parallels Forums: <strike>https://forum.parallels.com/threads/apple-silicon-support-for-amazon-linux-2.357286/</strike> (deleted)

Reddit thread using UTM: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/rxat5m/run_amzn2_kvm_arm64xfsgptqcow2_image_onprem_with/

Comment: is this the x86_64 or the arm64 version of amazon linux? (does the latter still exist?)

Comment: It's `arm64`, but in `.qcow2` format for KVM.  I've hard-linked the download above.  There's also an [arm64 container image here](https://cdn.amazonlinux.com/os-images/2.0.20220419.0/container-arm64/).

Comment: In regards to "does the latter still exist", I'd expect the latter to grow in popularity over time due to [Amazon rolling it's own ARM64 processor](https://aws.amazon.com/pm/ec2-graviton/) ([Graviton 1, Graviton 2, Graviton 3, etc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annapurna_Labs#AWS_Graviton_(AL73400))).

Comment: ah sorry, must have somehow slipped my attention :) yeah, I'd expect the same